# How to merge two linked lists in O(1) time in c?

Tags: c, linked-list

Given two lists l1,l2, show how to merge them in O(1) time. The data structures for the lists depends on how you design it. By merging I mean to say union of the lists.

Eg: List1 = {1,2,3}
List2 = {2,4,5}

Merged list = {1,2,3,4,5}

Comment: Is that even possible?

Comment: Sounds like this is part of your "facebook telephonic interview". ;)

Comment: I can do it in O(0) using a computer I bought from Honest Mike's Parallel Dimension shop.

Comment: @tyler .. :O how do you know that..?? i m just preparing for that..

Comment: @vaibhav I have cameras in your house.

Comment: Either that, or I looked at your SO question history, and you asked about preparing for it yesterday.

Comment: your terms are not sufficiently precise, I think. what properties to you assume on the elements of the lists? What properties do you assume on the lists themselves? What is the merge criteria? If it is just set union, as one might understand from your example, then indeed an implementation of lists with head and tail would do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you are looking for is not an *algorithm* to merge two "lists" in O(1) time. If you read "lists" as "linked lists" then this cannot be done faster than O(n).

What you are being asked to find is a *data structure* to store this data in that supports merging in O(1) time. This data structure will not be a list. It is still in general impossible to merge in "hard" O(1) time, but there are data structures that support merging in *amortized* O(1) time. Perhaps the most well-known example is the [Fibonacci Heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_heap).

Comment: But the question refers to `union` operator not `merge` despite of its title

Comment: Union and merge are frequently considered synonyms in the context of data structures.

Answer (score 11):

#### On "merging" two sorted lists

It is straightforwardly impossible to merge two sorted lists into one sorted list in `O(1)`.

About the closest thing you can do is have a "lazy" merge that can extract on-demand each successive element in `O(1)`, but to perform the full merge, it's still `O(N)` (where `N` is the number of elements).

Another close thing you can do is physically *join* two lists ends to end into one list, performing no [merge algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_algorithm) whatsoever, such that all elements from one list comes before all elements from the other list. This can in fact be done in `O(1)` (if the list maintains head and tail pointers), but this is not a merge by traditional definition.

---

#### On set union in `O(1)`

If the question is about what kind of set representation allows a union operation in `O(1)`, then yes, this can in fact be done. There are many [set representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28computer_science%29) possible in practice, each with some pluses and minuses.

An essential example of this specialized representation is the [disjoint-set data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union-find_algorithm), which permits a `O(α(n))` amortized time for the elementary *Union* and *Find* operations. `α` is the inverse of the [Ackermann function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function); where as the Ackermann function grows extremely quickly, its inverse `α` grows extremely slowly. The disjoint-set data structure essentially offers amortized `O(1)` operations for any practical size.

Note that "disjoint" is a key here: it can not represent two sets `{1, 2, 3}` and `{2, 4, 5}`, because those sets are not disjoint. The disjoint set data structure represents many sets (not just two), but no two distinct set is allowed to have an element in common.

Another highly practical set representation is a [bit array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_array), where elements are mapped to bit indices, and a `0`/`1` indicates absence/presence respectively. With this representation, a union is simply a bitwise *OR*; intersection a bitwise *AND*. Asymptotically this isn't the best representation, but it can be a highly performant set representation in practice.

Comment: Why impossible? Just have the next pointer of l1 point to the head of l2.

Comment: @GregS That's an append operation, not a merge operation (union). The merge/union would eliminate duplicate elements.

Comment: @Greg What if l1 and l2  have duplicates?

Comment: @Johannes Based on the example given in the question, it's clearly not supposed to be a multiset.

Comment: Thanks, you're right, the poster clearly used the word "union".

Answer (score 0):

I am not that experienced so please do not hit me hard if I say something stupid.

Will this work ? Since you have two linklists how about you connect 
on the last element of the first list
the first element of the second list ? We are still talking about pointers right ? the pointer of the last element of the list is now pointing to the first element of the second list.

Does this work ?

Edit : but we are looking for the union. so I guess it wont...

Answer (score -1):

You make use of the fact that a PC is a finite state machine with 2^(bits of memory/storage space) states and thereby declare everything `O(1)`.